# Improving extraction of points of interest for image preprocessing

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

I'm currently developing a task for image classification.
The images are hand drawn, in black and white, and relative simple shapes (a house, circle, etc.)

For that, I'm using a SIFT approach:

```
def getData(folder, min_num_descr = 20):
    lista_imagenes = []
    for x in os.listdir(folder):
        path_local = folder + "/" + x
        for j in os.listdir(path_local):
            imagen = cv2.imread(path_local + "/" + j)
            lista_imagenes.append(imagen)
    
    lista_total_kp = []
    lista_total_desc = []
    lista_total_imagen = []

    for i  in range(len(lista_imagenes)):
        sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
        kp_1 = sift.detect(lista_imagenes[i], None)
        kp_1, dec_1 = sift.compute(lista_imagenes[i],kp_1)
        lista_total_kp.append(kp_1)
        lista_total_desc.append(dec_1)
        lista_total_imagen.append(i)
    
    lista_desc_numpy = np.array(lista_total_desc)
    lista_desc_real = []
    for i in range(0,len(lista_total_desc)):
        try:
            if lista_total_desc[i].shape[0] >= min_num_descr:
                lista_desc_real.append(lista_total_desc[i][:min_num_descr])
        except:
            continue
            
    return np.array(lista_desc_real)
```

This is giving me a dataset (I added the targets in the last column)

```
df_splitted = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/norhther/datasets/main/drawn_images.csv").iloc[:,1:]
```

The problem is that after a `StandardScaler` and several models with fine tunning (SVM, AdaBoost, RF...) I'm having some bad scores. I also added class weight to `estables` and `evolutivos` because the dataset is imbalanced, and also those classes are most important.

My question is how to improve the image preprocessing, maybe using another technique and not  the points of interest with SIFT.

Comment: Some stuff that comes to my mind: 1) Are your images 8-bit-per-pixel? 2) You say your dataset is imbalanced. Try classifing just 2-3 classes and see what happens with your results. If they are good (not just "better") after *reducing* the scope, you're having a variance problem (need more data).

Comment: the answer given below merely lists a bunch of feature descriptors that are already eclipsed by SIFT. you won't gain anything from them. that's my opinion anyway.

Comment: hand-drawn, black-and-white... that'll require some serious machine learning. best results to be gained with deep learning. local feature descriptors aren't gonna help. there's no amount of "preprocessing" that'll make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I may suggest you to look in to other technique like:

Features from Accelerated Segment Test (FAST)

- Key point detection only (no descriptor, we can use SIFT or SURF to
  compute that)
- Used in real time applications

Here you can find the papers on FAST

https://www.edwardrosten.com/work/rosten_2006_machine.pdf

Binary Robust Independent Elementary Features (BRIEF)

- Computers descriptors quickly (instead of using SIFT or SURF)
- it is quite fast.

Here you can find the paper on BRIEF

[http://cvlabwww.epfl.ch/~lepetit/papers/calonder_pami11.pdf](http://cvlabwww.epfl.ch/%7Elepetit/papers/calonder_pami11.pdf)

Oriented FAST and Rotated BRIEF (ORB)

- Developed out of OpenCV Labs (not patented so free to use!)
- Combines both Fast and Brief

Here you can find the paper on ORB

http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf